# screensharing "cancel button"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigator

In my app, I have set up screenshare functionality - when a button is clicked, it calls **navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia**

After that, I capture, create a stream, add an event listener to it, establish a WebRTC connection and transmit via socket

One problem remains, if I press screenshare and cancel - how do I catch this event?

I can provide some details if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using getDisplayMedia Promise:**

When you call navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia, it returns a promise. This promise can be resolved with a MediaStream if the user accepts the screen sharing request or rejected if the user cancels it. To catch the event when the user cancels, you can attach a catch block to the promise chain.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true })
  .then(mediaStream => {
    // User accepted screen sharing
    // Set up WebRTC connection
  })
  .catch(error => {
    if (error.name === 'NotAllowedError') {
      // User cancelled screen sharing
      console.log('Screen sharing was cancelled by the user.');
    } else {
      // Handle other errors
      console.error('Error accessing screen sharing:', error);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! I marked your answer as correct. My solution is somewhat different, but yes - sometimes it happens that you miss the most obvious things.

Comment: In my case, the only difference is that I call via async / await, but in this case I use try / catch, I just need to catch the moment when it is the cancellation of sharing (capture) and when it is the lack of a camera, but for this I have there is a flag system

Comment: And it surprises me who gave me and you a minus, let this "specialist" argue at least